# Get DidEndScroll Delegate Method from Custom UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, delegates

I am using the a custom UITableView called UIBubbleTableView.

In my View Controller that I am setting up the `UIBubbleTableView` everything works fine. I however am trying to implement lazy loading so I need to know what cells are visible. Unfortunately I can't access the UITableView delegate method of the UIBubbleTableView. I tried looking around StackOverflow and I read chaining delegates is a good idea. So I am creating a delegate in `UIBubbleTableView.h`

However when I put in 
`@property (nonatomic, weak) id<UIBubbleTableViewDelegate> delegate;`

I got 
`Property type 'id<UIBubbleTableViewDelegate>' is incompatible with type 'id<UITableViewDelegate>' inherited from 'UITableView'`

Is chaining delegates really the best method or is there another solution. I thought about using NSNotification, but I am guessing that has performance implications.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> I can't access the UITableView delegate method of the UIBubbleTableView

Why on earth not? Of course you can! After all, UITableView's delegate gets `scrollViewDidScroll` not because it is a UITableView but because it is a UIScrollView. Well, so then does UIBubbleTableView. It is both a UITableView *and* a UIScrollView. That is what inheritance means.

You do not need to declare a `@property`. UIBubbleTableView already has a `delegate` property, inherited from its superclass, UITableView. Again, that is what inheritance means. Just set the delegate the way you would for any table view, either in code or through an outlet. There is no need to declare anything, no need to chain anything. The table view delegate is the UIBubbleTableView delegate.

If you need *another* delegate (one for some UIBubbleTableView delegate protocol methods and another for the UITableView delegate protocol methods) then you will have to give that property a different name, won't you?

Comment: actually this method doesn't work because the UIBubbleTableView needs to be a delegate as well as the parent view controller. If I set the ParentViewController to the delegate, BubbleTableView has lost the delegate. If I am correct, only one VC can be a delegate.

Comment: Well, I don't know anything about UIBubbleTableView. But for a table view to be the delegate of *itself* is bad design.

Comment: However, if that is an absolute requirement (i.e. the UIBubbleTableView is the delegate of itself), then you will have to implement `scrollViewDidScroll` in the UIBubbleTableView as well, and pass the message along to an actual controller as needed.